# How are bean validation constraint violation errors caught/shown by JSF?

Tags: jsf, error-handling, bean-validation

When I try to submit a JSF form referring an entity with bean validation annotations on its properties, then JSF displays the bean validation errors when the bean validation constraints are violated.

I wonder:

- When is the entity validated?
- How is it handling/linking bean validation errors to the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *When is the entity validated?*

During the JSF validations phase, which is the 3rd phase of the JSF lifecycle, between gathering and applying the submitted values (2nd phase) and updating the model values (4th phase) in.

---

> *How is it handling/linking bean validation errors to the view?*

Any validator (and converter) exception message is turned/stored in a [`FacesMessage`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html) which is added to the `FacesContext` by `FacesContext#addMessage()`. All those messages are in turn individually displayed in either a `<h:message>` component which is bound to a specific input component

```html
<input id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
<h:message for="foo" />

<input id="bar" value="#{bean.bar}" />
<h:message for="bar" />
```

or all together in a generic `<h:messages/>` component

```html
<h:messages />
```

All missing validation messages will be logged to the stdout, or when you're running in development project stage, in the development stage warning messages which is automatically added to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Validation happens after the Request values are submitted to the server but before they are applied to the Model Bean. This ensures the integrity of the Model. There is a data type conversion during this process and if JSF standard validators and converters are not enough to validate your data type, you can plugin your own. This tutorial describes [standard validators and converters](http://johnderinger.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/validators-and-converters/) available in JSF.

For writing custom validators, refer to [O'Reilly's book on JSF](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005399.do).

Comment: Please note that OP is talking about JSR303 Bean Validation (those annotations like `@NotNull`, `@Pattern`, `@Min`, `@Max`, etc) which also has its own ways of creating custom validators. This is unrelated to JSF's own validators.